# how can i implode multi dimentional array

Tags: php

I am retrieving an array values from database which save multi dimensional array..i want to add

***|***

between two member values of array..i have tried basic implode function which mention in the end what i tried..

i have loop mention below

```
$sql = "SELECT `categories` FROM `jos_js_res_record` WHERE `categories` LIKE '%Autumn Market Session%' OR `categories` LIKE '%Farmer Market Profiles%' OR `categories` LIKE '%Spring Market Session%' OR `categories` LIKE '%Summer Market Session%' OR `categories` LIKE '%Winter Market Session%' ORDER BY `user_id`";

$db->setQuery( $sql );

$unserial = $db->loadObjectList();

foreach ($unserial as $dataElement) {
  $categories = unserialize($dataElement->categories);

if (is_array($categories)) {

foreach ($categories as $unserKey => $unserailData) { 

print $unserailData;
    }

}

echo '<br />';

}
```

**i have tried the below line of code in 2nd for each loop but that shows error**

```
$comma_separated = implode(",", $unserailData);
```

Kindly guide me how can i implode the values in 2nd array **$unserailData** ?

**data in $unserailData look like below**

> Summer Market Session
>
> Summer Market Session
>
> Summer Market SessionAutumn Market Session
>
> Summer Market SessionAutumn Market Session

Comment: @Mischa sorry cant add <br /> in  comment let me add it in my question

Comment: @Mischa i have edited my question please see the values above

Comment: @Mischa actually i want to add **|** between two market sessions

Comment: the below code for implode which i used does'not work..i dont know why some one mark it un researched..i have already did many tries..

`$comma_separated = implode(",", $unserailData);`

Comment: @Mischa
**i tried the below code but it also doesnot work**
`$values = array_map('array_pop', $array);
$imploded = implode(',', $values);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work, if I'm reading your request correctly:

```
$sql = "SELECT `categories` FROM `jos_js_res_record` WHERE `categories` LIKE '%Autumn Market Session%' OR `categories` LIKE '%Farmer Market Profiles%' OR `categories` LIKE '%Spring Market Session%' OR `categories` LIKE '%Summer Market Session%' OR `categories` LIKE '%Winter Market Session%' ORDER BY `user_id`"; 

$db->setQuery( $sql ); 

$unserial = $db->loadObjectList(); 

foreach ($unserial as $dataElement) { 
    $categories = unserialize($dataElement->categories); 
    if (is_array($categories)) {
         echo implode('|', $categories);
    } elseif (is_string($categories)) {
         echo $categories;
    }  
    echo '<br />'; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks..i have also create another technique, mentioned in next comment, but yours is more clean i use your ones..thank you

Comment: **i made this trick**
`foreach ($categories as $unserKey => $unserailData) {

 $arr2[] = $unserailData;
 }
$imploded = implode(" | ", $arr2);

print_r($imploded);
$arr2 = array();`

Comment: You're welcome - but also give yourself a pat on the back for actually finding a solution yourself as well. Even if it is long-winded :) , it's a solution!

Comment: Yup true :) i was also trying, but i know you senior guys can give me a better solution & can guide me better like you did above:)

Answer (score 0):

i made the below trick but the code mentioned @Robbie is more clean so i replace my code with his code.

**I made this trick**

```
foreach ($unserial as $dataElement) {
  $categories = unserialize($dataElement->categories);
if (is_array($categories))
{ 
foreach ($categories as $unserKey => $unserailData) {
$arr2[] = $unserailData;
}
$imploded = implode(" | ", $arr2);
print_r($imploded);
$arr2 = array();
}

else{
echo "Category not stored correctly";
}
echo '<br />';
}
```